# Cumulative difference between dates for a particular column value in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to subtract dates in 'Date' column based on the number in 'Mobile_Number' column

```
Mobile_Number    Date    

0503477334    2018-10-28
0506002884    2018-10-28
0501022162    2018-10-30
0503477334    2018-11-05
0506002884    2018-11-08
0503477334    2018-11-12
```

The result should be

```
Mobile_Number    Date      Difference

0503477334    2018-10-28      0
0506002884    2018-10-28      0
0501022162    2018-10-30      0
0503477334    2018-11-05      8
0506002884    2018-11-08      11
0503477334    2018-11-12      7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), replace missing values and converting to `integers`:

```
df['Difference'] = df.groupby('Mobile_Number')['Date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   Mobile_Number       Date  Difference
0      503477334 2018-10-28           0
1      506002884 2018-10-28           0
2      501022162 2018-10-30           0
3      503477334 2018-11-05           8
4      506002884 2018-11-08          11
5      503477334 2018-11-12           7
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761711/how-to-encode-a-pandas-row-with-custom-values