# How to encode a pandas row with custom values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to encode the row values of the selected column in pandas.

For example, let's assume I have the following dataframe

```
    Col_A  Col_B
0    SV     NT
1    NT     P
2    SV     I
3    P      SV
4    I      P
```

I have a dictionary containing the encode values for each row of a column like below

```
encode_values = { 
    "Col_A" : {"NT": 1, "SV": 0, "P": 1, "I": 0},
    "Col_B": {"NT": 10, "SV": 0, "P": 10, "I": 0}
}
```

I want a new dataframe with the custom encodings for each of those columns

Result: -

```
    Col_A  Col_B
0    0     10
1    1     10
2    0     0
3    1     0
4    0     10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `apply` and `map` using column names:

```
print (df.apply(lambda d: d.map(encode_values[d.name])))

   Col_A  Col_B
0      0     10
1      1     10
2      0      0
3      1      0
4      0     10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `replace` with dictionary as parameter, apply separately to each series in the df:

```
df.Col_A = df.Col_A.replace (encode_values['Col_A'])
df.Col_B = df.Col_B.replace (encode_values['Col_B'])
```